# Compare two columns and fill in the third column in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns in excel like this:

```
 ColA colB
  a1     X
  b      a1
  c      b
  d      Y
         c
```

I want the result as

```
 ColA colB  colC
  a1     X    X
  b      a1
  c      b
  d      Y    Y
         c
```

I have tried using VLOOKUP and INDEX. However, nothing worked for me.

Basically wanted to find the values that are present in ColB but not present in ColA.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: you could check out this site for more info https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/04/21/get-list-unique-values-excel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use VLOOKUP, if match then nothing, if no match then the value:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,$A$2:$A$6,1,FALSE)),B2,"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another solution

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1,$A$1:$A$4,0)),"",B1)
```

Drag/Copy down as required.

[image]